# OPP Classes with sql statement

Tags: php, sql

I want to set a PHP variable within my SQL `SELECT` statement that can then be used on another page. Here is my code:

```php
<?php    
class Page extends DbConnect 
{
    public function getPage() 
    {    
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_name = 'Contact'";
        $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch()) 
        {    
            echo $row['page_name'];
        }
    }
}    
?>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please add more details on your question? Why and what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, I'm wanting to select data from a MySQL database table depending on what page your on. In this case it's the contact page. That data is then used to pull in a template file. I need to set a variable that can be used on another page. I would usually do $page_name = $row[page_name]; not sure if that's any clearer.

Comment: Can't you just pass a `variable` on a class's `__construct()` ?

Comment: within the sql statement? not sure how to do that. Very new to oop and php classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a variable on a class's construct and assign it to a private or public variable

```
<?php

class Page extends DbConnect 
{

    private $page;

    public function __construct($toView){
        $this->page = $toView;
    }

    public function getPage() 
    {
        $pageToView = $this->page;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_name = '$pageToView'";
        ...

    }

}
```

```
<?php
// on contact page
$page = new Page('contact');
$page->getPage();
```

```
<?php
// on about page
$page = new Page('about');
$page->getPage();
```

You can also pass a parameter directly on a class's function

```
<?php

class Page extends DbConnect 
{

    public function getPage($pageToView) 
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_name = '$pageToView'";
        ...

    }

}
```

```
<?php
// on contact page
$page = new Page();
$page->getPage('contact');
```

```
<?php
// on about page
$page = new Page();
$page->getPage('about');
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm using a single controller file to pull in a template page based on the page name. So I can't add individual code to each page. Can't I simply declare a public variables within the while loop and call them like $page_name = $row['page_name']?

Comment: Here is the code from my controller file.  $template->render('view/themes/' . $theme. '/' . $page_name);

Comment: is the template class extending the page class?

Comment: No, all I want to do is create a variable $page_name within my while loop.